# Обратная анимация CSS3 (когда убираем курсор)

Tags: css3, css-animation

При наведении курсора на объект, происходит анимация на css. Когда курсор убираем, анимация снова работает, с теми же параметрами и в том же порядке.

---

Когда наводим на прямоугольник в этом блоке:
1) слева и справа надвигаются "шторки" (полупрозрачные голубые прямоугольники)
2) сверху спускается кнопка "подробнее"

Когда убираем курсор с прямоугольника:
1) "шторки" раздвигаются
2) кнопка "подробнее" улетает обратно наверх.

**Можно ли изменить порядок анимации, чтобы когда УБИРАЕМ курсор, сначала
улетала кнопка "подробнее", а уже потом раздвигались шторки?**

(анимация при наведении при это должна остаться в таком порядке, в котором есть сейчас).

Comment: Уберите ссылку на сайт и добавьте нужный кусок кода в сам вопрос.

Comment: ну ты помог, дружище! ой спасибо! все проблемы решил просто.

Comment: Это сайт вопросов и ответов, а не рекламы сторонних сайтов или починки чужих проектов. За последнее обычно платят деньги. Поэтому оформите вопрос соответствующим образом, дабы Вам помогли с решением данной проблемы.

Answer (score 3):

Не с кнопками и шторками, но идея, я думаю, понятна:

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.stage1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #afa;
    transition-property: width;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-delay: 0.75s;  /* <<<=== */
}
.container:hover > .stage1 {
    width: 50px;
    transition-delay: 0s;  /* <<<=== */
}
.stage2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #aaf;
    transition-property: height;
    transition-duration: 1s;  /* <<<=== */
}
.container:hover > .stage2 {
    height: 50px;
    transition-delay: 0.75s;  /* <<<=== */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="stage1"></div>
    <div class="stage2"></div>
</div>
```